# Copy of a SQL Server CE Database Asks For Password When i Try To Open It

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce

**Hi Experts**

I am writing a Winforms application in C# with a SQL Server CE database, I created a backup of the `Database.sdf` file using `File.Copy()` method and everything worked as expected.

But when I try to open the recently created `BackUpDatabase.sdf` file with SSMS to check out the backup, it says

> *The Specified file is either not a valid SQL Server Compact File or it is corrupt. Would you like to repair it?*

When I click **yes**, another dialog "Connect to Server" appears which says

> *Cannot connect to G:\DataBaseBackUpFile.sdf.*
>
> *The password specified for the source database is incorrect. [ Data Source = G:\DataBaseBackUpFile.sdf ] (SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider)*

Now I request you experts to kindly help me to figure this error out

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *i Created a BackUp of the Database.sdf file using File.Copy() Method* Was the `.sdf` file closed when you tried this?

Comment: @@ ta.speot.is , yes i closed the connection to the database before copying it.

Comment: Is it a version 4.0 file? You cannot open that in SSMS...

Comment: Thanks Mr.ErikEJ for your reply , No  the version is 3.5.8080.0,  Can you please suggest me a tutorial / article Defining the creation of backup of sqlce database using c# thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **ALMIGHTY**
it is Done..

in the first case i was using   ***databasePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath+@"\Database.sdf");***    now i used  ***databasePath =     Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath+@"\Database.sdf")***;

and it is working ..

i thanks all  you experts for everything.